# Intermittent Internet Interruptions

Tags: internet, ping, modem, lag

I've been having internet issues for some time now. Browsing web pages is mostly a non issue; once in a blue moon a webpage will timeout. This happens on my wired laptop and and smart TV. My major issues are streaming and gaming. Seemingly at random the be huge lag spikes, rarely it gets so bad I get a disconnect/timeout. I'm running 75mbps.

I'm plugging my laptop directly into the modem for all testing, a Hitron CGN3 supplied by my ISP, no coax splitters. Speed tests are fine. Signal is from 5.9 - 7.2dBmV except for a single channel at 0.3dBmv on the 279 frequency. SNR is 37.6 - 40.9. The only thing that really looks off at is when I ping websites and the modem. I've gotten pings spikes in previous tests to google.com at 300+.

```
Pinging google.com [172.217.0.238] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=200ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=129ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=118
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=118

Tracing route to google.com [172.217.1.174]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     4 ms     3 ms     9 ms  INTEL_CE_LINUX [192.168.15.1]
  2    28 ms    29 ms    23 ms  23-233-52-1.cpe.pppoe.ca [23.233.52.1]
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    43 ms    50 ms    24 ms  kitchener.tsi-rcable.tor2.teksavvy.com [104.195.128.213]
  5    22 ms    33 ms    37 ms  ae10-0-bdr01-tor2.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.92]
  6    15 ms    20 ms    23 ms  ae12-0-bdr01-tor.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.10]
  7    24 ms    30 ms    28 ms  72.14.212.134
  8    26 ms    36 ms    31 ms  108.170.250.225
  9    16 ms    40 ms    15 ms  108.170.226.223
 10    31 ms    28 ms    27 ms  yyz10s04-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.1.174]

Trace complete.
```

The modem ping is what's concerning me the most.

```
Pinging 192.168.15.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=72ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
```

Is this normal? Is there something else I should be checking? What should I be telling my ISP? This problem can be as often as every five minutes and as few as once in a hour. I don't want them to run a quick test and be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a modem issue, because it is very rare to find a bad modem to causes like this.

I have several modems on 3G 4G Coaxial and ADSL. If you got spikes in a random way, that usually because:

- The ISP server connection issue (you can't do anything about this one)
- There is one of your programs on the computer loading something or using this resource making it spikes at random. (This is highly likely to make your connection suddenly drop high ping)

I recommend you find the second cause because it usually comes from that.

Comment: I have a multitude of devices, not just a PC with this issue.

Comment: If what you stated are true: "I'm plugging my laptop directly into the modem for all testing", can you check the firewall setting on your modem? because my built-in firewall in my modem is always causing my modem to behave abnormally after I upgrade my firmware.

Comment: I tried disabling it and am getting the same spikes. You might be right that it's my ISPs connection.

Comment: it could be bad coaxial or fiber optic, you should ask the ISP technician to check whether your modem is defective or there is a problem with their ISP.